# What is a verb that means "to move ungracefully?"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, verbs

I'm looking to fill in this blank with a single word that means "moved ungracefully."

'...he ______ into the room."

I've considered *galumphed*, but this has the connotation of a large, awkward body, and the character in this instance is of the skinny, nerdy type.

I've considered *bumbled*, but this has the connotation of purposelessness, and the entrance into the room is directed and purposeful.

Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: @Jim I'm going with lurch. Too bad I can't accept this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider ***lurch***.

Defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lurch) as:

> Make an abrupt, unsteady, uncontrolled movement or series of movements; stagger.
>   *‘the car lurched forward’
>
>   ‘Stuart lurched to his feet’*

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest he [***plodded***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=plodded) into the room, or [***clambered***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20clambered&oq=define%20clambered) into the room.

(He might also *stumble* or *stagger* into the room, though in Scotland you can achieve this gracefully).

Comment: How do we do that then?